# (require 'package) is newly very slow on Windows

Tags: package, debugging

In recent weeks, `(require 'package)` takes **minutes**.  This only happens on Windows, not on macOS or GNU/Linux.  What is going on?  `emacs-version` is `GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-11-15`.

Resolution (see below):  It turned out **not to be a problem with Emacs** at all.

Comment: That's not a great question for this site, though you might luck out and get a helpful answer. Do you see the problem also when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, consider filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew If I start without `.emacs` the startup is instantaneous.  So I went through the `.emacs` sexp-by-sexp.  It was `(require 'package)` very close to the top of the file that was taking a lot of time, and it never used to.  I didn't make any recent changes that would be a natural first thing to undo.  I've been a happy Emacs user for 30+ years on many platforms, but suddenly startup time on Windows got ridiculous.

Comment: So it sounds like your recipe to repro this is to (1) start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and then (2) do `M-: (require 'package)`. Is that right? If so, please consider reporting that recipe to Emacs: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew: Ok, I'll do that, as soon as `M-: (require 'package)` finishes evaluating.  Oh, there, it just answered `package`.  That took about two minutes.  Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` and hitting C-g while it's evaluating. Include the resulting backtrace in your report.

Comment: @npostavs Thanks, done: Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  call-process("c:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/minghc-7.10.2-x86_64/git-2.4.5.1/usr/bin/gpg.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--with-colons" "--list-config")
  apply(call-process "c:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/minghc-7.10.2-x86_64/git-2.4.5.1/usr/bin/gpg.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--with-colons" "--list-config"))
  epg-config--make-gpg-configuration("c:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/minghc-7.10.2-x86_64/git-2.4.5.1/usr/bin/gpg.exe")
  epg-find-configuration(OpenPGP)
  #[0 "\300\301!\205

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it's something to do with gpg, can you edit the backtrace into your question and/or add it to the [bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=26321) so we can read it properly?

Answer (score 2):

I followed @npostavs's guidance and it turned out, in the stack trace, that MinGHC (a Haskell environment) had a `gpg.exe` that was on the PATH that was causing problems.  @npostavs noticed that the MinGHC project is dead, and along with the notice of MinGHC project death was a suggestion to use Stack.  (I actually have Stack on the Windows computer involved as well.)  I removed MinGHC from the Windows computer and the problem I reported went away completely.  So this was **not an Emacs problem at all**, but a problem with something on the PATH that got in the way as `(require 'package)` was trying to do its job.

Thank you Emacs community for your help and suggestions.